# Javascript array sort put string MAG250 at bottom and other items at top ASC

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have ul elements with li elements inside...i need to when i dynamically add li element to sort with ASC but MAG250 needs to be put on bottom and others items at top...here is example in jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/hjzxumjd/1/
```

So input is this:

```
AAA aaa (64)
BBB (130)
DDD ddd (26)
GGG ggg (253)
MAG250 AAA (0)
MAG250 CCC (0)
MAG250 BBB (0)
MMM (254)
```

and i need to get this when function sortUnorderedList('test') is called:

```
AAA aaa (64)
BBB (130)
DDD ddd (26)
GGG ggg (253)
MMM (254)
MAG250 AAA (0)
MAG250 BBB (0)
MAG250 CCC (0)
```

So as you can see i get at top strings sorted ASC and then it follows sorted by ASC string that contains word MAG.

I try function that is in jsfiddle but i im unable to archieve this in javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create a regular expression to match against (in this case `^MAG250`) and if this is the case, then append those to a separate array. Before adding it back to the DOM, you merge the two arrays again.

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending, last) {
    var lastItems = [];

    if(typeof ul == "string") {
        ul = document.getElementById(ul);
    }

    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("A");
    var vals = [];

    for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(last.test(lis[i].innerHTML)) {
            lastItems.push([lis[i].innerHTML, lis[i].id]);
        } else {
            vals.push([lis[i].innerHTML, lis[i].id]);
        }
    }

    lastItems.sort(sortByText);

    vals.sort(sortByText);

    if(sortDescending) {
        lastItems.reverse();
        vals.reverse();
    }

    vals = vals.concat(lastItems);

    for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
        lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i][0];
        lis[i].id = vals[i][1];
    }

    function sortByText(a, b) {
        return a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
    }
}

sortUnorderedList('test', false, /^MAG250/);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hjzxumjd/7/

Alternatively you could try a custom sort.

Comment: Thanks this working perfect....as it should be..and code is simple and short...thanks...i accepted this answer.

Comment: it is working but found one error...when you for example see BBB (130) its a id is 3 when sorted out it id is 2...can you please update code so that a ID's and li ID's are same like in original when sorted? Please kindly help. Thanks

Comment: So you want that BBB (130) keeps the ID 3?

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, the sort can be replaced with a custom sort, where a normal string comparison is used if the items both are 'mag's, otherwise non mags come first:

```
                  var ismag = function(a){return a.slice(0,3) =='MAG';};
                  vals.sort(function(a1,a2){
                      var m1 = ismag(a1), m2 = ismag(a2); 
                      if(m1===m2)return a1.localeCompare(a2); //if both are 'mag' or neither is, use string comparison
                      return m1 - m2;
                  });
```

Implemented in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjzxumjd/2/)

For the check on an item being 'mag', a helper function is used here (`ismag`). In the implementation here, the text is checked on beginning with 'MAG' (there is an ES6 [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function if compatibility is not an issue). If the sort order really has to look at `contains` as mentioned in the description, the helper function can be changed to `var ismag = function(a){return a.indexOf('MAG') !== -1;};`

Answer (score 0):

Your JS Fiddle example already sorts the Array by ASC for me in both Firefox and Chrome.

You could attempt invoke your own sort function to insure the compare results.

```
 vals.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a >  b;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sort array manually. You can remove specific elements and then push it into sorted array. Following is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hjzxumjd/5/) depicting it.

#### Code

```js
// Updated Code

var rawArray = ["AAA aaa (64)",
  "BBB (130)",
  "DDD ddd (26)",
  "GGG ggg (253)",
  "MAG250 AAA (0)",
  "MAG250 CCC (0)",
  "MAG250 BBB (0)",
  "MMM (254)"
]

function sortArray(array) {
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a < b) return -1;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  return array;
}

function customSort(array) {
  var magArr = [];
  var retArr = [];
  array.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row.indexOf("MAG250") >= 0) {
      magArr.push(row);
    } else {
      retArr.push(row);
    }
  });

  retArr = sortArray(retArr);
  magArr = sortArray(magArr);

  magArr.forEach(function(row) {
    retArr.push(row);
  })
  return retArr;
}

function createHTML(array) {
  var html = "";
  array.forEach(function(row, index) {
    html += "<li id'" + index + "'>" + row + "</li>";
  });
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = html;
}
var sortedArray = customSort(rawArray);
createHTML(sortedArray);

// Original Code

function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string") ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("A");
  var vals = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  vals.sort();

  if (sortDescending) vals.reverse();

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

sortUnorderedList('test');
```

```html
Your Code:
<ul id="test">
  <li><a id="1">AAA aaa (64)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="2">DDD ddd (26)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="3">BBB (130)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="4">MMM (254)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="5">GGG ggg (253)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="6">MAG250 AAA (0)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="7">MAG250 CCC (0)</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="8">MAG250 BBB (0)</a>
  </li>
</ul>

My Code
<div>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution features a temporary array and a two level ordering.

```js
var array = ['AAA aaa (64)', 'BBB (130)', 'DDD ddd (26)', 'GGG ggg (253)', 'MAG250 AAA (0)', 'MAG250 CCC (0)', 'MAG250 BBB (0)', 'MMM (254)'],
    mapped = array.map(function (el, i) {
        var o = { index: i, value1: '', value2: '' };                
        if (el.substr(0, 3) === 'MAG') {                    
            o.value1 = el;
        } else {
            o.value2 = el;
        }
        return o;
    });
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value1.localeCompare(b.value1) || a.value2.localeCompare(b.value2);
});
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return array[el.index];
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Bonus: An even shorter version:

```js
var array = ['AAA aaa (64)', 'BBB (130)', 'DDD ddd (26)', 'GGG ggg (253)', 'MAG250 AAA (0)', 'MAG250 CCC (0)', 'MAG250 BBB (0)', 'MMM (254)'],
    result = array.map(function (el, i) {
        return { index: i, value: (el.substr(0, 3) === 'MAG' ? '2' : '1') + el };
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
    }).map(function (el) {
        return array[el.index];
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```